# Jekyll and liquid templating with custom domain

Tags: dns, jekyll

I have my Jekyll site on Github pages which is being forwarded to my domain with Digital Ocean. I got my domain working but realized that using this code
 {{ link.title }}

that my nav is being redirected back to my Github pages site.
I tried to add my domain name to my config file but then everything breaks.
Can I still use liquid templating? Is there a better way?

Comment: And you repository url is ?

Comment: myname.githubio/projectname/

Comment: I meant to add this     <a href="{{site.url}}{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>  Do I need to change my url links?

Comment: Be sure to use `url: yourdomainname.tld` not myname.githubio. And {{ site.url }} is only necessary in rss feed. For assets (css. js, img) and link you can use relative links.

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "http://jmstan.github.io"
baseurl: "/portfolio4"
```

Call assets like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/main.css">
or
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/logoexample3.png">
```

Links are like this :

```
<a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a>
```

Comment: You're welcome. And maybe, you can approve my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to, but it says I don't have the reputation yet.